# Difference between NIDS and NBA

Tags: ids

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between NIDS (**N**etwork-based **I**ntrusion **D**etection **S**ystem) and NBA (**N**etwork **B**ehavior **A**nalysis)

It is to my understanding that

NIDS use two detection methods :

- Signature-based detection
- Anomaly-based detection

and NBA use one detection method :

- Anomaly-based detection

Both use network "Anomaly-based" detection and both analyse the same kind of sample (packets). Note that NIDS also has a Signature-based detection. Is NBA just a lighter version of NIDS or is there a difference in the way it does Anomalyse-based detection ?

Comment: I didn't do my due diligence efficiently and found this question too which brings some answer : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33116/intrusion-prevention-systems-nips-vs-nba

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NIDS are designed to inspect the network at certain points, like at ingress/egress points in the network. Its focus is *intrusion*. Yes, there are signature rules and there are anomaly rule sets, but they focus on the point where traffic passes the NIDS inspection point.

NBA looks at the *network*. It's looking at bandwidth and protocol use and other factors across the network. It can gather data from across all network devices and work out what is weird/unusual.

And, as per usual in this field, definitions will mutate and change over time as both technologies start to "meet in the middle" and do each other's jobs.

Comment: Can we consider that NIDS is more stateless that NBA because NIDS is more about performing a packet inspection at instant `t` while NBA is more statefull and try to correlate packets together ?

Comment: No, you can't go that far

Comment: I'm still not sure I get the difference then. Especially, I do not get this sentence : _Yes, there are signature rules and there are anomaly rule sets, but they focus on the point where traffic passes the NIDS inspection point._  Could you rephrase it ?

Comment: It's the difference between a microscope and a scanner. One inspects the details and makes conclusions. The other takes in a broad understanding and makes conclusions.